# Custom Control lacking standard properties

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, custom-controls, programmatically-created

Following is a custom control called JobTimer created by inheriting/extending the standard control Timer. Purpose: In order to get a custom property named JobID added to the control.

```
public class JobTimer : System.Windows.Forms.Timer
{
    private int IntJobID;
    public int JobID
    {
        get{return IntJobID;}
        set{IntJobID = value;}
    }
}
```

These controls are getting created programmatically during run-time. Following is the code that does this:

```
public static void CreateTimer(int JobID) 
{
    JobTimer ControlJobTimer = new JobTimer();
    ControlJobTimer.Name = "JobTimer" + JobID.ToString(); //Error occurs here. 
    ControlJobTimer.Enabled = true;
    ControlJobTimer.JobID = JobID;
    ControlJobTimer.Interval = 30000;
    ControlJobTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(JobTimer_Tick);
    ControlJobTimer.Start(); 
}
```

Problem I am facing here, is that I am not able to "set" the standard property Timer.Name for this control.

ERROR: 
NameSpace.JobTimer does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type NameSpace.JobTimer could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
![enter image description here][1]

Even if the following line of code is supposed to set the name for this control as "ControlJobTimer"

```
JobTimer ControlJobTimer = new JobTimer();
```

Shouldn't I still be able to "Rename" a control at run-time? To my knowledge, this is doable with standard controls and should be a possible option with custom controls as well.

My requirement is that I want to be able to set a naming convention for the timer controls created at run-time. Please look into this and let me know what I am missing and if there is a workaround to achieve this function.

Comment: What error are you getting? (Not sure enabling it first is a good idea either)

Comment: That is the error that occurs there?

Comment: @Sayse: I have added the error message. Also placed the enabling line of code next to the naming line of code.

Comment: prgSRR - Looking at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), Timer isn't a control which is why it is erroring, It in fact, does *not* have a name property

Comment: @Sayse: Thanks for the finding. What is puzzling though, is that these controls (both the standard Timer control and the custom JobTimer control) have a Name property when dragged onto a form in design-time. Any insights on this?

Comment: What is the use of *renaming* control at run-time? If you give control a name at design time, then it is accessible by that name in code and can be compiled. But why would you want to name `label1` differently? If you think to use name to reference specific timer, then simply have storage (`Dictionary<>`), using form `components` is not the best storage, I'd say it's purely for form autogenerated code (to dispose all components). You can implement disposing of your timers explicitly, on form closing or application exit.

Comment: @Sinatr: Yes, I was initially hoping to reference the timers with the name but then I came up with the custom property "JobID" for that purpose. So it is just a matter of naming convention or standards at this time. As for the disposing of these controls, it seems to happen automatically when application stops, so that is not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst the Windows Forms designer shows a (Name) in the Proprties window, the control itself doesn't have a `Name` property - The designer just uses this to name the member variable that holds the reference to the control.

There's nothing to stop you adding a Name property though, although, as you say, you already have the JobId so that code can tell which timer it is.